# AppWidgetProvider of an sticker widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, appwidgetprovider

guys.

I'm creating a sticker widget, witch is basically an image (in some dimension) that the user can put at the home screen. It does absolutely nothing.

The idea is to sell a sticker with some logos of a nonprofit organization, so it can work as a donation, let's say. There are 5 different logos and that's it.

I have to create the AppWidgetProvider, but all changes is going to happen in the settings activity. So, my question is: what exactly do I put in the AppWidgetProvider? Can I leave it empty? O_o

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your talking about about passing something through the AppWidgetProvider(), yes you keep it empty. However, when it is enabled your going to have to pass the context it's in.

Comment: Thanks, man. I tried everything before answering, but it worked perfectly. All that I needed was implementing the onUpdate() method. But it in the widget where the user is prompted to select a logo (otherwise the logo would be re-set when the user turn off and back on the phone/tablet.)